# How can I load and draw predefined chart images (diagrams) rule based and related to a point vector layer with QGIS

Tags: qgis, mapping, rule-based

I have a bunch of diagrams for a set of route segments, stored as PNG, PDF or SVG with a regular name (topic-segment-id.(png|pdf|svg) for example), representing a certain aspect (like crossing rate or and angle for ships at a segment (..see graphics, polar density plots).

[image]

I'm able to generate the images of the diagrams (including a subsequent image processing chain) with a name carrying the segment-ID. I can also create a point layer for the placement of the diagrams, with  attributes for the filename and/or the segment-ID,  at the map (..see map points 1 to 17 corresponding to the diagrams above)  along the route.

[image]

How can I load and place the segment related images (the generated diagrams for example) at the addressed points/segments for the corresponding map under QGIS wit the print composer/ map layout tool. I want to have something like that:

[image]

PS: I use the statistic language R to create diagrams and  the point layer (package sf) and QGIS to generate the maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can represent raster images or svg's in points. The main thing is to add an attribute with the complete path.

Here is the result (they are squared because I was hurry, but you can do it rounded for sure):
[image]

Here is what I did:

1. Put all the images in a folder. In this case, I extracted the images from yours using gimp and saving the circles in jpg.
2. Add the path to the table of attributes.
3. Go to simbology and within the point set it to show raster/svg and then, instead of selecting just an image, go to the right button and set it as parameter (in my example the attribute represented is 'IMAGE'). If it is correctly stablished, the button will be yellow now.
4. If you want to keep points and images separated, you must duplicate the layer and show one of them as points. Then just represent the images with the desired displacement (depending on your representation).

[Here you have a video of the process](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3PMAQMAPXH8).

Here some screenshots:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Brillant, especially the video. I assume with an URL instead of a file, I can design a dynamic implementation via by a non QGIS/Python generated chart engine like R.

Comment: Absolutely. QGIS + R is a win win. You can do more than everything.